# VMWare access between different VMs

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have installed VMWare workstation 9.0.2 build-1031769 on my Windows 7 Laptop.
Then I have created **2 Windows 2003 VMs**.

I have 2 Network connections under my network adapter settings.
They are VMNet1 and VMNet2

Virtual Server 1 details as folows.
**Network Type: Custom (VMNet1) - Host Only

IP address: 192.168.229.128

Sub net: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 192.168.229.1**

Virtual Server 2 details as folows.
**Network Type: Custom (VMNet2) - Host Only

IP address: 192.168.150.110

Sub net: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 192.168.150.1**

I need to access **(Need to ping, share files)** between these two virtusal machines.
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

At any point during copying and pasting the above details between your system and here did it occur to you to wonder if "Host Only" appearing in the Network Type might mean anything?

You've set both VMs up to only be able to communicate with the host system. To network them you need to set them both up to be connected to the same network. You can set up a *bridged* connection, connecting them both to the same network as the host machine, which will allow them to communicate with each other, the host, and any other machines on your network, or you can create a custom network just for the two guests.

[This](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net.html)  should explain a few concepts.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to do it ?

Comment: Well no, because I don't have a copy of VMWare Workstation to hand, and I'm not going to download one to figure it out for you. I've given you everything a professional sysadmin should need to figure it out for themselves. There are even headings for "Host Only Networking" and "Bridged networking" in the document I linked for you, same or similar to the terms I used above.